# Why is my href tag directing to a different function?

Tags: python, html, django

I am working on getting a website up and running with Django 2.2. I am attempting to get a sidebar put together and I figured the first step is make sure I am linking to the right place and then go from there. On my html template I have links so that students can view assignment details and on the sidebar there should be links so students can go to course pages. Currently the href is using the views 'assignment_page' function instead of the 'course_page' function.

I have researched into what I should be doing inside the anchor href tag and I feel like I am doing it right as the assignment links work. Looking below you can see the structure of the href tag for the assignment and the course links are the same but the course link doesn't point in the right place.

Here is the html template:
This the the course link I discussed

```
{% for course in student_courses %}
<div>
    <a href="{% url 'view_course' course.title %}"> {{ course.title }} 
    </a>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Here is the assignment link

```
{% for assignment in course_assignments %}
<div>
    <a href="{% url 'view_assignment' assignment.title %}"> {{ 
    assignment.title }}</a>
    <p>Due Date: {{ assignment.due_date }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see, the href points to the path in urls.py with the name 'view_course' for the first one and 'view_assignment' for the second set.

Here are the relevant urls from urls.py:

```
path('<assignment_title>/',assignment_page, name='view_assignment'),
path('<course_title>/', course_page, name='view_course'),
```

So they are named right

that means they should call the respective views of 'course_page' and 'assignment_page'

Here are those views:

```
def assignment_page(request, assignment_title):
    print('\nAssignment\n')
    current_assignment = Assignment.objects.get(title=assignment_title)
    return render(request, 'assignment.html', 
           {'assignment':current_assignment})

def course_page(request, course_title):
    print('\nCourse\n')
    current_course = Course.objects.get(title=course_title)
    return render(request, 'course.html', {'course':current_course})
```

I could tell from those print statements that when I clicked on the Course link, it went to the assignment_page function from the view as it printed

Assignment

in the server output.

So the expected result is that it should direct to the basic course.html page and not the assignment.html page. The Error I get is saying an assignment of the name of the course, in this case, CS 120, does not exist, that is a course name so that is expected, but it shouldn't be using the Assignment.objects.get().

Any help would be appreciated, sorry for the long post

EDIT: 
Here is the entire urls.py in the app:

```py
"""superlists URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
    from django.conf.urls import url, include
    from django.contrib import admin
    from .views import course_page, assignment_page
    from django.urls import path


    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('<assignment_title>/',assignment_page, name='view_assignment'),
    path('<course_title>/', course_page, name='view_course'),
    ]
```

Here is the entire models.py:

```py
    from django.db import models
    from django import forms
    from django.conf import settings
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    import string
    import random
    from email.message import EmailMessage
    import smtplib


    def email_password(sender, recipiant, password):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(password)
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = recipiant
    msg['Subject'] = 'Password for Socrates'

    smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    smtp_server.send_message(msg)
    smtp_server.quit()



    class Student(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(default = '', max_length = 50)
    email = models.CharField(default = '', max_length = 40)
    number = models.IntegerField(default = '')
    year = models.CharField(default = '', max_length = 19)

    def add_info(self, info):
        self.name_parts = info[3].split()
        self.name = self.name_parts[1] + ' ' + self.name_parts[0][:-1]
        self.email = info[6]
        self.number = int(info[2])
        self.year = info[-1]
        self.save()

    def create_account(self):
        password = self.password_gen(8)
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=self.name_parts[1] + '.' + self.name_parts[0][:-1], 
            password=password, 
            email=self.email,
            first_name=self.name_parts[1],
            last_name=self.name_parts[0][:-1]
            )

    def password_gen(self, size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + 
        string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase):
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.data_list = []
        self.tag_list = []

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if data not in ['\t', '\n']:
            self.data_list.append(data)        

    def feed_file(self, file_path):
        ofile = open(file_path, 'r')
        f = ofile.readlines()
        for line in f:
            self.feed(line)

    def print_data(self):
        for student in self.data_list:
            print(student)

    def sort_data_list(self, start_char='\t\t\t', stop_char='\t\t'):
        # Sorts the data list compiling all of the data for each student into 
    sperate lists
        new_data_list = []
        will_append = False
        for entry in self.data_list:
            if entry == start_char:
                will_append = True
                student = []
            elif entry == stop_char:
                if will_append == True:
                    new_data_list.append(student)
                will_append = False
            if will_append and entry is not start_char:
                student.append(entry)
        self.data_list = new_data_list


    class Course(models.Model):

    Class_File = models.FileField(upload_to='class_htmls')
    code = models.CharField(default='', max_length=20, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(default='', max_length=50, blank=True)
    term = models.CharField(default='', max_length=60, blank=True)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, 
    related_name='enrolled_students')
    course_instructor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def create(self, file=None):
        if file is None:
            file = self.Class_File.path
        Parser = MyHTMLParser()      
        Parser.feed_file(file)
        Parser.sort_data_list('\t\t\t', '\t\t')
        course_info = Parser.data_list[0][1].split(' | ')
        self.student_info = Parser.data_list[2:]
        self.code = course_info[2]
        self.term = course_info[0][11:]
        self.title = course_info[3][:course_info[3].find(' (')]
        self.save()
        self.add_students()
        self.save()

    def add_students(self):
        students_in_db = Student.objects.all()
        for info in self.student_info:
            student_in_db = students_in_db.filter(number=info[2])
            if student_in_db.count() == 1:
                new_student = student_in_db.first()
            elif student_in_db.count() == 0:
                new_student = Student()
                new_student.add_info(info)
                new_student.create_account()
            self.students.add(new_student)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    class Assignment(models.Model):

    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, 
    null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    #assignment_creator = models.CharField(default=request.user)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Spacing is a bit off but here are all the models I use.

Comment: How is django supposed to tell whether a specific string is an assignment or a course?

Comment: The part in the href in '' should direct to the urls/paths to use. The href with the 'view_course' should direct to the url with name = 'view_course'.

Comment: But the only component of your URL is a string. There is no way for Django to tell what that string refers to. It will always just pick the first matching pattern, which is assignment.

Comment: If your referring to the string '<assignment_title>/' in 'urls.py, as far as I could tell, that was a variable that you pass to the respective views. I need that variable space for specifying what object to retrieve from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update path

```
path('assignment/<assignment_title>/',assignment_page, name='view_assignment'),
path('course/<course_title>/', course_page, name='view_course'),
```

Comment: After changing the relevant info to get those urls to work, it kept to the same error

Comment: are you sure after restarting the server and get the same error?

Comment: I did not restart the server, you got it to work, thanks a ton. So what did I do wrong?